# wicket 9: how to test downloading a resource

Tags: wicket

I have a component which allows a user to download an excel file after clicking a link.
It works and everything is fine, but I don't know how to write a test for this component.
I want to write a test to check if after pressing a link a file is sent to a client.

And so, my component looks like this

```
Link<Void> calculationsLink = new Link<>("calculationsLink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {

        AbstractResourceStreamWriter rStream =
                new AbstractResourceStreamWriter() {

                    @Override
                    public void write(OutputStream output)
                            throws IOException {
                        output.write(MyApp.class
                                .getResourceAsStream(pathToCalculations)
                                .readAllBytes());
                    }
                };

        ResourceStreamRequestHandler handler =
                new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(rStream, "calculations.xslx");
        getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(handler);
    }
};
```

My test is

```
@Test
public void calculations_file_downloaded_Successfully() {
    // then start and render the base page
    tester.startPage(HomePage.class); <-- link is located in a HomePage

    tester.clickLink("navBar:calculations", false); <-- link is clickable 
    tester.getResponse();//????

    tester.assert???(?????); <-- how to assert and what to assert?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `tester.getLastResponse()` and assert on its properties.

`tester.getResponse()` is the MockHttpServletResponse that will be used for the next HTTP call.

Some dummy examples:

```
assertEquals("application/octet-stream", tester.getLastResponse().getContentType());
assertEquals(3, tester.getLastResponse().getBinaryContent().length);
assertArrayEquals(new byte[] {1, 2, 3}, tester.getLastResponse().getBinaryContent());
```